# ColdFusion combine base64 chunks from web service into binary file

Tags: xml, web-services, coldfusion

I'm consuming a web service that returns large files in base64 chunks. When the web service only returns 1 chunk I can use toBinary() to convert and save to a file. But I'm not sure what to do when I get back larger files that are broken into chunks of base64 strings. A simple variable concatenation does not work. Is there a proper way to join these strings in Cold Fusion and then convert toBinary?

```
<cfset masterChunk = masterChunk & theNextChunk />
<cfset binaryFile = toBinary(masterChunk) />
```

The error I get is: must be a base-64 encoded string.

Comment: What are the actual values of masterChunk and theNextChunk when that error occurs?

Comment: I can perform a toBinary() on masterChunk and theNextChunk individually and not get an error. So I guess they are 2 valid base64 strings. If you want the actual strings, I'll have to post them somewhere else as they are over 1mb each.

Comment: In theory, you should just be able to concatenate the strings and decode. What happens if you try and decode the two strings separately?

Answer (score 1):

(Just to throw out a few more ideas ...)

Concatenating multiple base64 strings worked fine for me, so there may be something more going on here. Hard to say without the actual strings.

That said, if the ultimate goal is saving the binary to a file, why not just append the decoded bytes directly to the file? It is simpler and can be used with physical files as well as those in `ram:///`:

```
    // open for appending
    output = FileOpen( "c:/path/to/file.ext, "append");

    // append decoded bytes
    FileWrite(output, binaryDecode(firstChunk, "base64"));
    FileWrite(output, binaryDecode(nextChunk, "base64"));
    // ... append more bytes

    FileClose(output);
```

If you really need an array, another possibility is using a  [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). Again, it is slightly simpler to use, and is suitable for moderate sized files. For larger files, a `ByteBuffer` is probably more memory efficient.

```
    baos = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();

    // append decoded bytes
    baos.write( binaryDecode(firstChunk, "base64") );
    baos.write( binaryDecode(nextChunk, "base64") );
    baos.close();

    // do something with the array (save to file, etcetera)
    FileWrite( "c:/path/to/file.ext", baos.toByteArray());
```

**Edit:**
Side note, `ToBinary` is deprecated. The docs recommend using [BinaryDecode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fc5.html) for new code.

Comment: Ok, I like the simpler syntax of ByteArrayOutputStream. How big would a moderate sized file be?

Comment: There is no fixed size. It depends on your configuration. The main difference between the two is how they handle the byte arrays. In some cases, ByteArrayOutputStream makes a copy, which obviously would require more memory. (Granted the code is already making at least one copy, when decoding the string, no matter which method is used). Also, some methods of the out stream are synchronized, whereas the ByteBuffer's are not. One way to mprove performance of the stream is to declare the size up front, when invoking `init()`. That saves the cost of resizing.

Comment: BTW, your question mentioned saving the data to a file. If that is the ultimate goal, it is likely more efficient to skip the extra hoops and just write to the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adapt what I found in this post:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1017-splitting-and-joining-a-binary-file-in-coldfusion.htm

```
<!--- create array to hold binaries --->
<cfset xmlBinaries = arrayNew(1)/>
<cfset xmlBinariesTotalLen = arrayNew(1)/>
<!--- append chunks --->
<cfset arrayAppend(xmlBinaries,toBinary(newBase64Chunk))/>
<!--- set up java buffer to hold binary chunks --->
                <cfset objByteBuffer = CreateObject(
                    "java",
                    "java.nio.ByteBuffer"
                    ) />

<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(xmlBinaries)#" index="i">
 <cfset arrayAppend(xmlBinariesTotalLen,ArrayLen(xmlBinaries[i])) />
</cfloop>

<!---allocate space in the buffer --->
<cfset arrBinFull = objByteBuffer.Allocate(
                    JavaCast(
                    "int",
                    (ArraySum(xmlBinariesTotalLen) )
                    )
                    ) />

<!---add binaries to the buffer --->
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(xmlBinaries)#" index="i">
<cfset arrBinFull.Put(
                        xmlBinaries[i],
                        JavaCast( "int", 0 ),
                        JavaCast( "int", ArrayLen( xmlBinaries[i] ) )
                        ) /> 
</cfloop>


<cfset myResponse.fullBinary = arrBinFull.Array() />
```